# Use induction to prove that the number of ways to use $m$ numbers to write a number $n=n_1+\cdots+n_m$ is $\frac{(n+m-1)!}{(n)!(m-1)!}$

Tags: combinatorics, induction

> The problem asks to use **induction** to prove that the number of ways to write $n\in \mathbb N$ as a sum of $m\in\mathbb N$ natural numbers, i.e., $$n = n_1 + \cdots + n_m, \quad n_i \in \mathbb N$$
> is given by $$\frac{(n+m-1)!}{(n)!(m-1)!}$$

---

**My attempt**:

I can solve this problem easily by using combinatorics, but it asks to solve by induction...

Let $P$ denote the above statement, currently I got base case $P(1,1), P(n, 1), P(1, m)$. Then I assume:

$P(n,m+1)$ and $P(n+1, m)$ are true to prove $P(n+1, m+1)$. Then I stucked here, I have no idea where to start without using combinatorics...

Any hints and answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [method of double induction](https://www.britannica.com/science/mathematical-induction#:%7E:text=The%20foregoing%20is,1%20and%201.), since $P(m, n)$ is on two variables simultaneously. In this version, inductive hypothesis forks into two clauses, one for $m ≥ a$ and the other $n ≥ b$, $a$ and $b$ being fixed integers. Thus, a straightforward formulation is as follows (there are subtler ones):

Basis clause: $P(a, b)$ is true.

Inductive clause 1: For all $m ≥ a$, if $P(m, b)$ is true, then $P(m + 1, b)$ is true.

Inductive clause 2: For all $n ≥ b$ and $P(m, n)$ is true for all $m ≥ a$, if $P(m, n + 1)$ is true for all $m ≥ a$, then

$P(m, n)$ is true for all $n ≥ a$ and $m ≥ b$.